# Why do I need PHP wrapper for Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm sure I'll be called six kinds of ignoramus for this, but I just can't find a straight answer online.  Why do I need a wrapper like facebook's php webdriver, if I installed (today, so the latest versions of) Selenium server and Selenium webdriver?  I'm working in PHP.

My sample test (below) works fine.  Does that mean that I don't need a wrapper, or possibly that I have one and don't know about it?

```
<?php
class test extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
{
    protected function SetUp()
    {
        $this->setBrowser("*chrome");
        $this->setBrowserUrl("http://www.google.com");
        PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase::shareSession(true);
    }

    public function testSubmitLead()
    {
        $this->open("/");
        sleep(5);
    }
```

Comment: Seems like you already are using a wrapper - the PHPUnit Selenium Extensions.

Comment: so that's really my question, if I'm using this, why do I need something else? or do I not?

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves, the extensions to PHPUnit are using Selenium RC. RC is deprecated, and has been for about 4 years. WebDriver is a completely different approach to browser automation, including a different API, and a different means of communication with the Selenium server. Future plans include the removal of the RC API and communication protocol, so migrating to a WebDriver-based library will enable your code to continue to work over the coming years.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your issue correctly my answer will be the next:
There isn't webdriver for PHP (for Java, C#, Ruby but not PHP), so if you want to use in in PHP you have to have a wrapper such as the one you told us about.